# SQS Extended - The input receipt handle is invalid

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk, amazon-sqs

We wrappered an existing queue with the extended functionality. Messages are able to be put on the queue, and we see the message body being stored on S3.

However, when the message is consumed we get the following stack trace:

```
com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.ReceiptHandleIsInvalidException: The input receipt handle is invalid. (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ReceiptHandleIsInvalid; Request ID: ba9421e9-a9d2-56ba-8e17-70ff7190f05a)
                        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182)
                        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770)
                        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489)
                        at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310)
                        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.invoke(AmazonSQSClient.java:2419)
                        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.changeMessageVisibility(AmazonSQSClient.java:485)
                        at com.amazonaws.services.sqs.AmazonSQSClient.changeMessageVisibility(AmazonSQSClient.java:1692)
                        at com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.AmazonSQSExtendedClientBase.changeMessageVisibility(AmazonSQSExtendedClientBase.java:1376)
```

Which happens when we attempt to change the visibility. Is that not supported?

```
                    sqsExtended.changeMessageVisibility(queueUrl, message.getReceiptHandle(), visibilityTimeout);
```

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this hasn't been implemented, nor does it try to warn you by throwing an exception when calling the method. There doesn't seem to be a reason to not be implemented, looking at the source code, it would be straightforward.

For our case, we are okay with relaying on the queue default value for this parameter and not setting each individually.